# Use mp3s in iTunes without duplicating them in new library

Tags: itunes

I have a folder on an external hard drive with my music. I want to use my external hard drive to house my iTunes library, but when I import my files, it begins to duplicate them all in the iTunes library folder. Why? I just want to import them into iTunes, not duplicate them. What's going on? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the option you need is in Preferences -> Advanced.

Uncheck "Copy file to iTunes Media folder when adding to library".

That should do it.